# Keep selection when moving between directories in vifm

Tags: vifm

By default, `t` is used to add files or directories to a selection in vifm. The selected items can then be used as parameters to filesystem operations (copy, delete, link, move, ..).

Is it possible to keep a selection when changing directories in vifm? Whenever I add items using `t` the selection is lost when I change the directory to select other items.

Answer (score 0):

You can append each target file to a register instead of using `t`. `"AY` yanks a file to register `a`. If you now change directory and `"AY` again in another file, the register `a` will contain the two files, as `:reg` shows.

You can then use commands that support registers (see comands with `[reg]` in the Vifm manual) to operate on those files. For example,

```
:put a
```

will put all files from the register `a` into the current directory.

A map will also make your life easier.

```
:nnoremap x "AY
```

will append files to the register by just pressing `x`.